# How do i follow a specific pattern of multiple nodes/relationships any number of times through a graph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following neo4j graph where a node beginning with "I" is of label "Information" and a node beginning with "F" is of label "Function":

```
(I0)<-[:requires]-(F1)-[:provides]->(I1)<-[:requires]-(F2)-[:provides]->(I2)<-[:requires]-(F3)-[:provides]->(I3)
```

I want to cypher query this graph to find all the data that is downstream (following the provides-requires relations) of node (F1). What cypher query would i need to find this?

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show what you've tried, and specific issues you're running into, including expected vs actual output of your query.

Answer (score 0):

for these situations, with rels in both directions (which makes "downstream" an unclear concept) ,I suggest to use apoc : https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.path/apoc.path.expandConfig/

You can also try

```
MATCH (I0)-[:requires|provides*]-(F1)
```

But this is risky given the probability of looping and again, the bi-directionality.

Comment: Best to post doc links as comments, not as answers. Also note that the OP hasn't shown any work of their own yet, which is why I commented under the question, for more details.